# Zebra Scanner and Angular

Tags: android, angularjs, react-native, nativescript

I have written an angular application and trying to get it to run on a Zebra TC20 Android Scanner.

Has anyone used the EMDK with nativescript?

Or has anyone used react native with angular?
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: is it angular or angularjs ? What do yo mean by `react native with angular` ?

Comment: Ists angular like on angular.io. Ive seen there is a wrapper/ library for react to use angulat in it but it is more an Experiment and in alpha phase since 2017 and not ment for production

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your plugin and then you can use the plugin in NativeScript app.
[Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Android-Plugins-Infrastructure), you can find the information aboyr how to create Android Plugin/its infrastructure/directory structure and all. For further reading on marshalling from Java to JS, you can refer [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js?_ga=2.58823726.263361737.1564705605-650227493.1564705605).

Now as far as Zebra scanner is concerned, they have EMDK for android that you can download and refer to their exposed API to include in your plugin.

Below is the URL for the sample code for scanning

http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/tutorial/tutBasicScanningAPI/

Comment: Thank you very much. What ive seen so far is that the emdk jar file is more or less just a wrapper file and the real library is on the device is this a problem? I have found unanswered questions on this here and in the zebra community. I will try it today an over the weekend abd will report my findings.